# c# convert console.writeline to a string

Tags: c#, string, console, invoke

I want a code that takes the text that was written on the console and put it on a string variable, plz.
Something like this:

```
string s = Console.WriteLine(Invoke(o, null));
```

I want it with console because if I invoke it without it I can't get the text from it.

I hope you understand it.

Comment: `Console.ReadLine()`?

Comment: Create wrapper function for `Console.WriteLine` where you will save all given text before write it to console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got what I want

```
using (StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            Console.SetOut(stringWriter);
            Console.Write(mi.Invoke(o, null));
            string allConsoleOutput = stringWriter.ToString();

            MessageBox.Show(allConsoleOutput, "Output");
        }
```

thank for every one!

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this directly. I think you can somehow do it by getting the console window object or something like that, but it's really not worth the time to do that when you just want the output of `Console.WriteLine`.

There are a lot of overloads of `Console.WriteLine`, but in the end all the overloads will convert the parameter to a string, using `ToString`. So, to put the output of `Console.WriteLine` in a string variable, just call `ToString` on the argument.

```
string s = Invoke(o, null).ToString();
```

What if you want to both print, *and* store the output? You can do it like this:

```
string s = Invoke(o, null).ToString();
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Comment: What I really is that my rich textbox will get this string. if I code richtextbox1.Text = Invoke(o, null).ToString(); it not working

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation of [`Console.WriteLine()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.writeline(v=vs.110).aspx), which will Writes the specified data, followed by the current line terminator, to the standard output stream. doesn't return anything to assign to a variable, it's return type is void

Answer (score 0):

If You Want Print Text :

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter a name");
```

If You Want Enter Any Text :

```
 string name = Console.ReadLine();
```

Try This Way.